# how to configure MEVN project for run in nginx intranet?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, vue.js

I'm new in vue, node, express and mongo api and using nginx, so anyone can tell me where I need to put the configuration of the port?

In my project I have a "client" folder and "server" folder, both of them has a port configuration for run the project, in which of these folders do I need to place the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is now in charge of ports 80 and 443.

Set your express app to listen to some port, let's say 8080.

```
app.listen(8080, function(){

});
```

Find your nginx config file. I'm using the default file found under `nginx/sites-available`

Edit the default server block to this

```
server { # simple reverse-proxy
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
  }
```

Nginx will now forward requests to your node app.